# Yii2 - Render _search.php file inside index.php of a view

Tags: php, view, yii2, render

i have a view folder called eventos in Yii2. This view is an image gallery.

The _view2.php is for display of the images to general public. It works quite well.

But now i want to create a globalsearch input text inside _view2.php.

There i have already a GridView widget for display the images, but i don't want to use the $searchmodel boxes so i disable them.

**What i want is to render the _search.php file with just one input field, inside the _view2.php file**

My problem is in rendering the _search.php inside the _view2.php file.

Here is the code for _view2.php:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'showOnEmpty'=>false,
    'summary'=>'',
    'showFooter'=>false,
    'showHeader' => false,
    'bordered' => false,
    'striped' => false,
    'hover' => true,
    //'options' => ['class' => 'grid-view'],
    //'layout' => "{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",

    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'id',
        //'nome',
        'descricao',
        'data',
        // No model -> getImageurl()
        [
            'label' => '',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=> function($data) { return Html::a(Html::img($data->imageurl, ['width'=>'300', 'height' => "170"]), $data->foto); },
        ],
        [
            'label' => '',
            'format' => 'raw',
            'value'=> function($data) { return Html::a(Html::img($data->imageurl2, ['width'=>'300', 'height' => "170"]), $data->foto2); },
        ],

        ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => ''],
    ],
]); ?>
```

And i need to render the _search.php inside the _view2.php.

Code for _search.php:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'globalsearch') ?>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SOLVED.

_view2.php code:

```
use yii\base\view;
echo $this->render('_search', array('model'=>$searchModel));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use renderPartial to display a partil view inside another

For example adding this:

```
<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_search', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

This is an example that is generated with gii by the way

Here is the code of a file view/create.php:

```
<?php
/* @var $this EventsController */
/* @var $model Events */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
    'Events'=>array('index'),
    'Create',
);

$this->menu=array(
    array('label'=>'List Events', 'url'=>array('index')),
    array('label'=>'Admin Events', 'url'=>array('admin')),
);
?>

<h1>Create Event</h1>

<?php echo $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>
```

As you can see the view 'create' loads the partial view '_form' that is the way you acomplish this. So you can reuse the _form view in another views like in the update view for example.

Comment: Yes. Since Yii1.1, but how can i render the primary view and then the partial view? Is in the controller actionView2? Can you give me an example, please?

Comment: You do put this code in the primary view I will give you an example I edit my answer

Comment: Throws error: Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::renderPartial()

Comment: Did you put this in the primary view?

Comment: Yes. i think i just need to use render(), instead of renderPartial().

Comment: Depends on your needs render('myview') will render the file 'myview', complete with the $layout that's specified in your controller.
renderPartial('myview') will render ONLY the contents for 'myview'.

Comment: It is solved. I used: use yii\base\view; <?php echo $this->render('_search', array('model'=>$model)); ?>

Comment: Many thanks Sandino. Your answer pointed me in the right path :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81695/discussion-between-sandino-and-andre-castro).

Comment: In a view file, $this refers to an instance of yii\web\View, not to a controller. View does not have a method renderPartial(), you should use render() instead.